# How to assign a shape to each series of values in iWork '09 Numbers?

Tags: formatting, charging, iwork-09, iwork-numbers

How can I assign a shape to each series of values in iWork '09 Numbers? Currently all series are forced to have the same shape, which makes them hard to distinguish on black and white prints.

Answer (score 2):

I tried many times and accidentally found an answer:

1. Click on the graph object itself
2. Click on the series
3. Make sure the Inspector is shown
4. Navigate on the Inspector > Chart > Series > Data Symbol
5. Select Data Symbol to choose a shape and adjust the number on the right to choose a suitable size